# How to run js-test-driver IE9 and document mode IE8

Tags: js-test-driver

How to run js-test-driver IE9 and document mode IE8 ?

Is it possible to do anything like this with meta tags or is there any config switch for this? We dont want to run in compability mode.

```
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by modifing the registry by setting FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION feature that  defines the default emulation mode for Internet Explorer to 8888 (0x22B8).

It is descibed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation

Note that your browser will use IE8 document mode always.